Pandas modify the original excel
I want to replace a value into an excel and then save it.
Using the following code I see that pandas is changing the format of the original excel.
writer = pd.ExcelWriter(str(Path.cwd())+'\file.xlsx', engine='openpyxl')
new_df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='test')
writer.close()

Basically I see that, if for instance in the original excel file, after the save everything is lost. Is there a way to save the existing "layout" of the original excel?



can you provide an example of what you mean?

done.added the pictures

it seems that there is no out-of-the-box method for that. you might have to change each cell value one by one.
See here for reference: Overwriting excel columns while keeping format using pandas
edit, below there is a solution that works using mode and if_sheet_exists in the ExcelWriter method

The xlwings package gives you control over the excel format. Below is a simple use case. For more control over the format use xw.range.options
import xlwings as xw
book = xw.Book('file.xlsx')
sheet = book.sheets.add('test')
sheet.range('A1').value = new_df
book.save()


I'm using pandas library

You can (and should) use both together.
